# No End Point Mapping Found Spring-Boot

Tags: spring-boot, web-services, soap, jaxb

I am using Spring boot 2.4.2 , and trying to create a SOAP Webservice from a given WSDL file.

My WSDL file looks like as following (................................ indicates omitted par as WSDL is very large):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:gsstype="http://com.alcatel.au/opennet/nbgateway/gsstypes" xmlns:gsstypes="http://com.alcatel.au/opennet/nbgateway/gsstypes" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://opennet.com.sg/opennet/OnGSSNorthBoundGateway/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://opennet.com.sg/opennet/OnGSSNorthBoundGateway/">
   <wsdl:types>
      <xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://com.alcatel.au/opennet/nbgateway/gsstypes">
         ................................
         <xsd:complexType name="CustomerPremises">
            <xsd:annotation>
               <xsd:documentation>CustomerPremises</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element name="SiteAddress" type="gsstypes:SiteAddress" />
               <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="HomePassedOrHomeReached" type="gsstypes:HomePassedOrHomeReached" />
            </xsd:sequence>
         </xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:complexType name="SiteAddress">
            <xsd:annotation>
               <xsd:documentation>Complex Address type which will be used as a base type for the rest of the Address.</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="BuildingTypeID" type="gsstypes:varchar10" />
               <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="AddressHouseNumber" type="gsstypes:varchar10" />
               <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="AddressStreetName" type="gsstypes:varchar100" />
               <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="AddressFloorNumber" type="gsstypes:varchar3" />
               <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="AddressUnitNumber" type="gsstypes:varchar5" />
               <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="AddressBuildingName" type="gsstypes:varchar64" />
               <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="AddressPostCode" type="gsstypes:varchar6" />
            </xsd:sequence>
         </xsd:complexType>
         ................................
      </xsd:schema>
      <xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://opennet.com.sg/opennet/OnGSSNorthBoundGateway/">
         ................................
         <xsd:element name="CustomerPremisesForSCRequest" type="gsstypes:CustomerPremisesForSCRequest" />
         <xsd:element name="CustomerPremisesForSCResponse" type="gsstypes:CustomerPremisesForSCResponse" />
         <xsd:element name="gatewayAuthentication" nillable="false" type="tns:AuthenticationInfo" />
         <xsd:complexType name="AuthenticationInfo">
            <xsd:annotation>
               <xsd:documentation>Represents authentication info. Will be passed with the request header</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element name="userName" nillable="false" type="xsd:string" />
               <xsd:element name="password" nillable="false" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:sequence>
         </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:schema>
   </wsdl:types>
    ................................
   <wsdl:message name="CustomerPremisesForSCRequest">
      <wsdl:part element="tns:CustomerPremisesForSCRequest" name="parameters" />
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="gatewayAuthentication">
      <wsdl:part element="tns:gatewayAuthentication" name="parameters" />
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="CustomerPremisesForSCResponse">
      <wsdl:part element="tns:CustomerPremisesForSCResponse" name="parameters" />
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:portType name="OnGSSNorthBoundGateway">
     ................................
      <wsdl:operation name="customerPremisesForSC">
         <wsdl:input message="tns:CustomerPremisesForSCRequest" />
         <wsdl:output message="tns:CustomerPremisesForSCResponse" />
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:portType>
   <wsdl:binding name="OnGSSNorthBoundGatewaySOAP" type="tns:OnGSSNorthBoundGateway">
      <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
       ................................
      <wsdl:operation name="customerPremisesForSC">
         <soap:operation soapAction="http://opennet.com.sg/opennet/GSSNetworkService/customerPremisesForSC" />
         <wsdl:input>
            <soap:header message="tns:gatewayAuthentication" part="parameters" use="literal" />
            <soap:body use="literal" />
         </wsdl:input>
         <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
         </wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:binding>
   <wsdl:service name="OnGSSNorthBoundGateway">
      <wsdl:port binding="tns:OnGSSNorthBoundGatewaySOAP" name="OnGSSNorthBoundGatewaySOAP">
         <soap:address location="http://10.65.111.157:8680/nb-workorder-gss/http/gateway" />
      </wsdl:port>
   </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

My configuration adapter looks like following:

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WeberviceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<Servlet> messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);

        return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(servlet, "/nlt/ws/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = "nb-workorder-gss")
    public Wsdl11Definition gssWsdl11Definition() {
        SimpleWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new SimpleWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setWsdl(new ClassPathResource("nb-workorder-gss.wsdl"));
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

}
```

And my End point looks like following:

```
@Endpoint
public class NBWorkorder {

    private static final Logger LOGGER =
              LoggerFactory.getLogger(NBWorkorder.class);
    
    @PayloadRoot(namespace = "http://opennet.com.sg/opennet/OnGSSNorthBoundGateway/", localPart = "gsstypes:CustomerPremisesForSCRequest")
    
    @ResponsePayload
    private CustomerPremisesForSCResponse customerPremisesForSC(@RequestPayload CustomerPremisesForSCRequest request) {
        LOGGER.info("i WAS HERE");
        CustomerPremisesForSCResponse response = new CustomerPremisesForSCResponse();
        ResponseMessage responseMsg = new ResponseMessage();
        responseMsg.setMessageCode("0X0000");
        responseMsg.setMessageDescription("This is testing ");
        responseMsg.setMessageHead("HEAD");
        response.setResponseMessage(responseMsg);
        ServingCabinetDetails scDetails = new ServingCabinetDetails();
        scDetails.setCOArea(AreaCode.AM);
        SiteIdentifier si = new SiteIdentifier();
        si.setSiteID("1212");
        si.setSiteType("CO");
        scDetails.setSiteIdentifier(si);
        response.getServingCabinetDetails().add(scDetails);
        return response;
    }
}
```

All the tutorials that I can find for Spring Boot Webservices:

https://medium.com/swlh/publish-a-soap-web-service-with-spring-boot-b561a4142d81

I am assuming this is use the targetNameSpace in wsdl and embeded xsd are same , which is causing problem for me and I am getting an erorr :

```
No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage {http://opennet.com.sg/opennet/OnGSSNorthBoundGateway/}CustomerPremisesForSCRequest]
```

Can someone help here .

My trace log looks like following:

```
Received request [<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:gss="http://com.alcatel.au/opennet/nbgateway/gsstypes" xmlns:ong="http://opennet.com.sg/opennet/OnGSSNorthBoundGateway/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <ong:gatewayAuthentication>
         <ong:userName>?</ong:userName>
         <ong:password>?</ong:password>
      </ong:gatewayAuthentication>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ong:CustomerPremisesForSCRequest>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <gss:SiteID>?</gss:SiteID>
         <gss:Postal_Code>?</gss:Postal_Code>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <gss:AdditionalParameter>
            <gss:Name>?</gss:Name>
            <gss:Value>?</gss:Value>
         </gss:AdditionalParameter>
      </ong:CustomerPremisesForSCRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>]
2021-01-26 22:52:33.041 DEBUG 13456 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] yloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping : Looking up endpoint for [{http://opennet.com.sg/opennet/OnGSSNorthBoundGateway/}CustomerPremisesForSCRequest]
2021-01-26 22:52:33.041 DEBUG 13456 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher  : Endpoint mapping [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping@40405125] has no mapping for request
2021-01-26 22:52:33.041 DEBUG 13456 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] oapActionAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping : Looking up endpoint for [http://opennet.com.sg/opennet/GSSNetworkService/customerPremisesForSC]
2021-01-26 22:52:33.041 DEBUG 13456 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher  : Endpoint mapping [org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.mapping.SoapActionAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping@1d5daf98] has no mapping for request
2021-01-26 22:52:33.041 DEBUG 13456 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher  : Endpoint mapping [org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping@4b9256d1] has no mapping for request
2021-01-26 22:52:33.041  WARN 13456 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.ws.server.EndpointNotFound           : No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage {http://opennet.com.sg/opennet/OnGSSNorthBoundGateway/}CustomerPremisesForSCRequest]
2021-01-26 22:52:33.041 DEBUG 13456 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.t.http.MessageDispatcherServlet    : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND, headers={}
```

soapui request as following:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ong="http://opennet.com.sg/opennet/OnGSSNorthBoundGateway/" xmlns:gss="http://com.alcatel.au/opennet/nbgateway/gsstypes">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <ong:gatewayAuthentication>
         <ong:userName>11</ong:userName>
         <ong:password>111</ong:password>
      </ong:gatewayAuthentication>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ong:CustomerPremisesForSCRequest>
         <gss:SiteID>11</gss:SiteID>
         <gss:Postal_Code>121212</gss:Postal_Code>
      </ong:CustomerPremisesForSCRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Adding more details in case :
Changing line:

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = "http://opennet.com.sg/opennet/OnGSSNorthBoundGateway/", localPart = "gsstypes:CustomerPremisesForSCRequest")
```

to:

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = "http://opennet.com.sg/opennet/OnGSSNorthBoundGateway/", localPart = "CustomerPremisesForSCRequest")
```

gives exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://opennet.com.sg/opennet/OnGSSNorthBoundGateway/", local:"CustomerPremisesForSCRequest"). Expected elements are <{http://com.alcatel.au/opennet/nbgateway/gsstypes}CustomerPremisesForSCRequest>
```

Comment: Not even a comment , looks like my question is way badly posted

Comment: You have a `CustomerPremisesForSCRequest` element in namespace `http://opennet.com.sg/opennet/OnGSSNorthBoundGateway/` and type in namespace `http://com.alcatel.au/opennet/nbgateway/gsstypes`, so probably you have two classes called `CustomerPremisesForSCRequest`. Are you sure you use the correct import in the endpoint?

Comment: No, that is not the issue , onGSSNorthBound is qualified Schema while gsstypes is supporting , if you see CustomerPremisesForSCRquest from OnGSSNorthBoundGateway refers to gsstypes

Comment: I can see the concerning lines in the `*.wsdl` file, but I am talking about the Java code. My guess is that the `CustomerPremisesForSCRequest` Java class is a class annotated with `@XmlType` and namespace `gsstypes`. If this is the case, change `CustomerPremisesForSCRequest` to `JAXBElement<CustomerPremisesForSCRequest>` in the parameters of the `customerPremisesForSC` method.

Comment: Yes  , this was the issue .